# Incorrect syntax near '.\'. in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I ran the query I am getting incorrect syntax error. can any one help me to fix it?

```
SELECT  
    si.SoftwareImage as ImagePLName, 
    SUBSTRING(si.SoftwareImage, 0, CHARINDEX(\'.\',si.SoftwareImage)),
    sib.SoftwareImageBuild as BuildID 
FROM 
    v000001.SoftwareProductBuilds spb 
JOIN 
    v000001.SoftwareProductBuildSoftwareImageBuilds spbisib ON spbisib.SoftwareProductBuildId = spb.SoftwareProductBuildId 
JOIN 
    v000001.SoftwareImageBuilds sib ON sib.SoftwareImageBuildId = spbisib.SoftwareImageBuildId 
JOIN 
    v000001.SoftwareImages si ON si.SoftwareImageId = sib.SoftwareImageId 
WHERE
    spb.SoftwareProductBuild = '123456'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would guess [SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
CHARINDEX('.\',si.SoftwareImage)
```

Documentation to [CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) for SQL Server

Documentation to [CHARINDEX](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X82257.htm) for Sybase.